# Turn off automatic collection of Purchase event only in Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-events

I am upgrading Facebook SDK for android to v5. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android#

I don`t want the Purchase event to be logged automatically since I have other payment gateways active apart from Google In-App. I am handling them manually. Since I am updating to v5 this event will be automatically sent along with the other 2 and if I switch it off then I will lose App Install and App Launch events which I need.

Is there any way by which I can continue with SDK automatically reporting **App Install** and **App Launch** events but not sent Purchase event automatically?

The guide also mentions that *"However, if you have disabled automatic logging, but still want to log specific events, such as install or purchase events, manually implement logging for these events in your app."* but I was not able to find any documentation about logging  **Install** and **App Install** manually.

I also found in the guide *"You can also disable automatic In-App Purchase event logging using the app dashboard. Go to the Android card under Basic > Settings and toggle the switch to No."* but it doesn`t specify how that will work with the other 2 events.

The way I see it, I will have to keep the automatic events on and filter out the Google In-App Purchase event from my custom pushing of Purchase event so that it is not duplicated.

Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?